# How can I get which application is locking a table/record in DB2 for i

Tags: db2, db2-400

When i run a stored procedure in DB2 for I i get an `SQL State 57033`, `Code -913`.
The message `[SQL0913] (translated from itailan) is: Row or object MYTAB00002 in MYLIB of type *FILE is in use. (...).`

When I try to update the same table with a regular `UPDATE MYTABLE SET FIELD=FIELD WHERE PRIMARY_KEY = ...` it succeeds when I update some rows but fails when I update some other rows, so I guess that this is a row-level lock.
I need further information to find the application that is locking these rows, how can i get those in DB2 for i? I'm using version 7.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the job that holds the lock using [`QSYS2.RECORD_LOCK_INFO`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=services-record-lock-info-view)

```
select
  *
from
  qsys2.RECORD_LOCK_INFO rli
where
  table_name = 'MYTABLE'
  and table_schema = 'MYSCHEMA'
```

There are other functions and views where you can find information about the job [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=services-work-management)

You also can see the current call stack of the job using [`QSYS2.STACK_INFO`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=services-stack-info-table-function) function